# Abgrenzung von Paradoxon und Oxymoron

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Zum Beispiel, ist der Begriff "rundes Quadrat" ein Oxymoron oder ein Paradoxon? Soweit ich die jeweiligen Definitionen verstehe, erfüllt es beide.

Das ist aber nur ein Beispiel, mir geht es um die generelle Abstufung, und zwar vorrangig darum, ob das eine ein "Teil" vom anderen ist. Etwa: Ein _ ist immer ein _, aber ein _ muss nicht unbedingt ein _ sein. Außer bei Konstruktionen wie _, da ist es überhaupt anders.

Ich würde sehr gerne selbstbewusst mit den Termen umgehen können, kann jemand für mich Licht darauf werfen?

Comment: Sind es nicht vor allem Begriffe aus völlig verschiedenen Fachgebieten (_Paradoxon_ Philosophie/Logik, _Oxymoron_ Rhetorik)?

Comment: Stimmt, das Oxymoron gibt es in der Logik nicht! Das Paradoxon scheint es jedoch in der Rhetorik zu geben (zumindest laut duden.de). Macht ja auch irgendwie Sinn, dass die Sprache die Logik beerbt. Ich bin beim Recherchieren in dieser Richtung über weitere Unklarheiten gestolpert, weiß aber noch nicht, wie sie elegant in die Frage eingebettet werden könnten. Wen's interessiert, es ist vorübergehend als html-Kommentar in der Frage versteckt.

Comment: Das ist eine interessante Frage, hat aber wenig mit "German Language" zu tun, sondern ist *sprachübergreifend*. Nützlich ist https://wortwuchs.net/stilmittel/paradoxon/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Paradoxon** ist ein Begriff, der aus der Logik, also aus einem Teilgebiet der Mathematik kommt. Das **Oxymoron** stammt hingegen aus der Rhetorik, also aus einem Teilgebiet der Sprachwissenschaften.

Daraus folgen schon unterschiedliche Definitionen:

Das Paradoxon ist eine *Aussage*, und jede Aussage hat einen Wahrheitsgehalt, der *wahr* oder *falsch* sein kann. Bei einem Paradoxon ist es nun aber so, dass die Annahme eines bestimmten Wahrheitswertes in einem logischen Schluss zur Erkenntnis führt, dass genau der andere Wahrheitswert zutreffend sein muss.

Ein klassisches Beispiel für ein solches logisches Paradoxon ist dieser Satz:

> Diese Aussage ist falsch.

Wenn man dem Satz Glauben schenkt, wenn man also die Aussage für wahr hält, stellt sich sofort heraus, dass das nicht zutrifft, weil der Satz ja aussagt, selbst falsch zu sein. Nimmt man nun aber an, der Satz wäre falsch, führt diese Negation dazu, dass der Satz wahr wird. Der Satz widerspricht sich also in jedem Fall selbst.

Ein **Oxymoron** ist hingegen keine logische Aussage, sondern ein *Begriff*. Oft genügt es schon, ein zusammengesetztes Wort zu bilden, dessen Teile für Dinge stehen, die einen Gegensatz darstellen:

- Oxymoron (griechisch: oxys = klug, moros = dumm)
- Plastikglas (entweder aus Plastik, oder aus Glas)
- Flüssiggas (zwei Aggregatzustände die einander ausschließen)

Oder man stellt vor ein Nomen ein Adjektiv, dass eine gegenteilige Eigenschaft des Nomes ausdrückt:

- alter Knabe
- stummer Schrei

Der wesentliche Unterschied aus sprachlicher Sicht ist, dass ein Oxymoron ein Begriff ist, während ein Paradoxon eine Aussage ist.

Wikipedia beschreibt auch noch andere Formen des Paradoxons, die aber keinen echten Widerspruch bedeuten, und die ich persönlich daher nicht zu den Paradoxa zählen würde:

- *Metaphysisches Paradoxon*: Eine Aussage, bei der klar ist, dass entweder sie, oder ihr Gegenteil zutrifft, bei der aber beide Möglichkeiten unmöglich zu sein scheinen. z.B.:

> Aussage: Das Universum hat einen Anfang.
>   Gegenteil: Das Universum hat keinen Anfang.

Für mich ist dieses Gegensatzpaar kein Paradoxon, weil hier kein Widerspruch vorliegt. Nur führen beide Annahmen zu Schlussfolgerungen, die unserer Intuition widersprechen (Aus beidem ist auf Wirkungen ohne Ursache zu schließen), was jedoch nur ein weiterer Beleg dafür ist, das die Intuition nicht immer recht hat.

- *rhetorisches Paradoxon*: Damit ist das Oxymoron gemeint, das ich ebenfalls nicht für ein Paradoxon halte, weil ein Oxymoron ja keine Aussage, sondern nur ein Begriff ist.

Wikipedia zählt auch noch das semantische Paradoxon auf, ohne auch nur mit einer Silbe anzudeuten, was damit gemeint sein könnte.

Auch erwähnt werden sollen die **scheinbaren Paradoxa**, also Aussagen, von denen man bei erster Betrachtung annimmt, sie wären falsch, während sie sich bei genauerer Betrachtung als wahr herausstellen (oder umgekehrt). Der Widerspruch existiert also nur zwischen Erwartung und Realität (oder zwischen Glauben und Wissen), ohne dass es einen echten inneren Widerspruch gibt.

Comment: @ALLCAPSWARLOCK: Wie ich bereits angedeutet habe, ist das Definitionssache. Ein »rundes Quadrat« ist ein Begriff, folglich ohne Zweifel ein Oxymoron. Entschließt man sich, die Kategorie »Oxymoron« als eine Form des Paradoxons (nämlich als rhetorisches Paradoxon) zu definieren, dann ist ausnahmslos jedes Oxymoron zugleich auch ein Paradoxon. Tut man das nicht, und behauptet nur Aussagen wären in der Lage ein Paradoxon zu sein, dann sind *Oxymoron* und *Paradoxon* einander ausschließende Kategorien, weil »das ist ein Begriff« und »das ist eine Aussage« einander ausschließen.

Comment: Was würdest du sagen: Reicht es – um als Paradoxon bezeichnet werden zu können –, dass etwas eine widersprüchliche Aussage impliziert (Beispiel: `rundes Quadrat` impliziert `Es gibt ein Q, das rund ist` aber `Alle Quadrate haben rechte Winkel` impliziert `Widerspruch`) oder müssen die letzteren Aussagen explizit dastehen.

Comment: @ALLCAPSWARLOCK: Wie schon gestern gesagt: Das hängt davon ab, wie man den Begriff »*Paradoxon*« definiert. Wenn man eine Definition wählt, die nur Aussagen als Paradoxa zulässt, dann können nur Aussagen Paradoxa sein. Entscheidet man sich aber für eine Definition, die auch Begriffe zulässt, dann muss man daraus nicht erst extra eine Aussage daraus machen.

Comment: Könnte man also für keine der beiden Definitionen behaupten, sie sei die vorherrschende bzw. die dem allgemeinen Verständnis des Wortes entsprechende? Das ist es nämlich, was ich zumindest annähernd in Erfahrung bringen wollte.

Comment: Danke auf jeden Fall für deine Antwort.

Comment: Ich persönlich hänge der Fraktion an, die den Begriff »Paradoxon« nur auf logische Aussagen anwendet, und daher das Oxymoron als etwas davon getrenntes ansieht. Ob es nun aber mehr Leute gibt, die meiner Meinung sind, oder ob eine Mehrheit die andere Definition für besser hält, weis ich nicht. Das müsste man in einer Abstimmung erheben. Aber egal wie diese Abstimmung ausginge: Du müsstest dich danach noch immer entscheiden was du für richtiger hältst, und ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es immer eine gute Idee ist, sich nach der Mehrheit zu richten.